# MySQL - optimising selection across two linked tables

Tags: mysql, join, union, distinct, key

I have two MySQL tables, states and trans:

states (200,000 entries) looks like:

```
id (INT) - also the primary key
energy (DOUBLE)
[other stuff]
```

trans (14,000,000 entries) looks like:

```
i (INT) - a foreign key referencing states.id
j (INT) - a foreign key referencing states.id
A (DOUBLE)
```

I'd like to search for all entries in trans with trans.A > 30. (say), and then return the energy entries from the (unique) states referenced by each matching entry. So I do it with two intermediate tables:

```
CREATE TABLE ij SELECT i,j FROM trans WHERE A>30.;
CREATE TABLE temp SELECT DISTINCT i FROM ij UNION SELECT DISTINCT j FROM ij;
SELECT energy from states,temp WHERE id=temp.i;
```

This seems to work, but is there any way to do it without the intermediate tables? When I tried to create the temp table with a single command straight from trans:

```
CREATE TABLE temp SELECT DISTINCT i FROM trans WHERE A>30. UNION SELECT DISTINCT j FROM trans WHERE A>30.;
```

it took a longer (presumably because it had to search the large trans table twice. I'm new to MySQL and I can't seem to find an equivalent problem and answer out there on the interwebs.
Many thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick, I've tested it in SQL Server 2008, so hopefully it works in MySQL too.

```
select energy from states
where id in
(
    select distinct i from trans where a > 30
    union
    select distinct j from trans where a > 30   
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Axarydax, but that's not quite what I need: I'd like a list of each of the unique (distinct) entries from the union of trans.i and trans.j such that trans.A>30, and for each id in this list, I'd like its state.energy value.
With your method, I only get those ids which match trans.j and I'll get duplicates within that list.
Thanks for your help,
Christian

Comment: Thanks again - I can see how that would work in one line.
But when I try it, the command takes a very long time to execute (10 minutes and waiting...), whereas by using intermediate tables it takes less than 10 seconds.
Do you know if there's a way to optimize your command in MySQL?

Comment: well the command should fine as it is - it tells database what to do, but not how to do it.

The database engine is looking over 200 000 000 records in 'trans' table and comparing each 'a' if it is < 30. Try creating index on 'a' column, it may help speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

OK... with a bit of help from Axarydax and others, I use the (essentially equivalent) command:

```
SELECT energy FROM states,
(SELECT i FROM trans where A>30. UNION SELECT j i FROM trans WHERE A>30.) temp
WHERE states.id=temp.i;
```

which works fast enough if I've got an index on i,j and A.